# Getting an "Internal System Error" on PHP pages

Tags: php, forms, server, localhost, dreamweaver

I am setting up a website with a simple login. I had it mostly set up on remote server, then decided to setup a test server. It was working well so I then uploaded my files to the remote server. Now I get an "internal system error" on all PHP pages. I'm new to PHP and using Dreamweaver. I have not found my particular situation here. The errors in DW point to the file below (line 9 specifically). I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

```
    <?php
    # FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
    # Type="MYSQL"
    # HTTP="true"
    $hostname_thelivingoracles = "localhost";
    $database_thelivingoracles = "thelivingoracles";
    $username_thelivingoracles = "username";
    $password_thelivingoracles = "password";
    $thelivingoracles = mysqli_connect($hostname_thelivingoracles,
    $username_thelivingoracles, $password_thelivingoracles) or 
    trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
    ?
```

Comment: You are only passing 3 parameters into the mysqli_connect on line 9 not 4. you are missing the database parameter. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when connecting to a specific database with mysqli_connect() the syntax would be:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

It looks like you've left out the name of your database?

```
$thelivingoracles = mysqli_connect($hostname_thelivingoracles,
$username_thelivingoracles, $password_thelivingoracles, $database_thelivingoracles) or 
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

Also, there is no closing '>' character at the end of your script, I presume this was a copy-and-paste issue though.

Comment: Thank you to the both of you. I will check into these things. I may have to come back, but hopefully not. Ha.

Comment: Again, thank you both that fixed my problem...now on to the next problem. Guess that will be another question soon.